# Tweepy. The function 'on_data' blocks the next part of code

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

Can you please tell me why when I use **on_data** and **on_response** function at the same time, the latter does not work? I understand that the first function contains all information, but I already wrote a lot of code using on_response function and I just wanted to get a small part of on_data function.

```py
class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):
   def on_data(self, raw_data):
      print(raw_data)
    
   def on_response(self, response):
      print(response) #this part of code is not working
```

Comment: what do you mean "it is not working" ?  this looks perfectly valid so long as you call the class in the same way....  can you provide and example of how it fails ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I mean that any actions that I add to the on_response function after on_data will not be executed and will not give any errors.

Comment: are you able to provide an example ?  for example,  how do you instantiate the class and where do you call the function ?  ...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the StreamingClient gets any data, `on_data` will be called. 
`on_data` takes in the raw data (the json) and converts it into Tweepy Objects and then calls other functions like `on_tweet`, `on_includes`, `on_errors`, and finally `on_response`.

And that's the reason why `on_response` is never called because you're overriding the default `on_data` function that would call `on_response`

---

Line 899 is where on_data is defined for the StreamingClient.
https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py#L899

Comment: Thank you very much, everything is in place now